# Shell script not running in crontab

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, cron

Following is my crontab entry

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
* * * * *  /FinalSync.sh $(date --date="5 days ago" +%d_%m_%Y) || echo $? >> log
```

Got no error in log file also

Shell Script

```
#! /bin/sh

source=/Source/$1
destination=/Destination
folderParam=$(basename $source)
if /usr/bin/rsync -avh -r $source $destination; then
   cp /FolderCopyStatus/Success   /Status/Success_$folderParam
else
   cp /FolderCopyStatus/Failure   /Status/Failure_$folderParam
fi
```

Script run perfectly when I use in command line as under

```
sh /FinalSync.sh  $(date --date="5 days ago" +%d_%m_%Y)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cron` converts `%` to newline for any `crontab` entry. You need to escape the `%`s with `\`:

```
* * * * *  /FinalSync.sh "$(date --date="5 days ago" +\%d_\%m_\%Y)"
```

Comment: changed but didn't work..

Comment: I wonder what's the history of using the percent sign for that...

Comment: Got 126 error code in log file

Comment: @ilkkachu probably just carried over from `printf` and similar functions.

Comment: @HadoopDev007 then that's a different issue. Please edit your question and update it with the current situation.

Comment: Return code 126 seems to imply a permission problem. Maybe you have exclusive execution rights on the script. Try `chmod +x FinalSyn.sh`.

Comment: @terdon after escaping I started to get error 126 which means (command not executable)..my cronjob still didnot run

Comment: @HadoopDev007 yes, I understand that but that is a different problem. So, ideally, accept this answer which solved your original issue and then ask a new question about the `126` error.